# Android-proguard-project for library

Tags: android, proguard

i used com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersGridView in my app...
this is my proguard-project.txt :

```
-keep class com.tonicartos.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.tonicartos.**
```

but this error Occurs:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(6213): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(6213): Process: com.myapp, PID: 6213
E/AndroidRuntime(6213): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(6213):     at   com.myapp.a.g.getCount(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(6213):     at   com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersSimpleAdapterWrapper.generateHeader    List(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(6213):     at com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersSimpleAdapterWrapper.<init>(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(6213):     at com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersGridView.setAdapter(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(6213):     at com.myapp.fragments.aj.run(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(6213):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(6213):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(6213):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(6213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime(6213):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(6213):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(6213):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(6213):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(6213):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

tnx for your help !

Comment: Is it working by disabling Proguard ? 
You can decode a obfuscated stacktrace by using the mapping file generated by proguard. See http://blog.simplyadvanced.net/android-how-to-decode-proguards-obfuscated-code-from-stack-trace/

Comment: tnx...yes it working by disabling Proguard ! tnx for link.